# gles20 Branch in Cocos2d-X

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I find that the *gles20* branch of Cocos2d-x is under active development. Link: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/tree/gles20

However, when I checked out the source, installed the Xcode templates with the included script, and created a simple iPhone project with the template, the code wouldn't compile.

I investigated the errors and found that some files (such as the *kazmath* folder, *ccGLStateCache.cpp* and *ccGLStateCache.h*) which were supposed to be located inside the *libs* folder, were in fact missing.

Those missing files are very likely caused by the Cocos2d-x template failing to copy those files from the original source to the new project's location.

My questions:

- Is the *gles20* branch ready for use?
- If yes, how can I fix my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just contacted one of the authors of Cocos2d-X, the answer is NO, the *gles20* branch is not ready for use yet. They expect to release an alpha version in 2 weeks. (Today is April 23, 2012).